# SpeechSynthesizer - save audio file without playing it to user

Tags: c#, blazor, azure-cognitive-services, speech-synthesis

I have this class, which uses Text-to-speech service from Microsoft. I want to save the audio file of the speech, but i don't know how to not play the sound to user on web(using Blazor Server app).

```
using Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech;

    public class TextToSpeechService : ITextToSpeechService
    {
        public async Task SpeakSsmlAndSaveToFile(string text, string filePath)
        {
            var speechConfig = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription("5c4d780b81cb40fca6bd555cc3148765", "westeurope");
            speechConfig.SpeechSynthesisVoiceName = "sk-SK-LukasNeural";
    
            string ssml = $"<speak version='1.0' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis' xml:lang='en-US'>" +
                          $"<voice name='sk-SK-LukasNeural'>{text}</voice></speak>";
            filePath = "wwwroot\\Audio\\DictationRecordings\\" + filePath;
    
            using (var speechSynthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer(speechConfig))
            {
    
                var result = await speechSynthesizer.SpeakSsmlAsync(ssml);
    
                if (result.Reason == ResultReason.SynthesizingAudioCompleted)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Speech synthesized for SSML: [{ssml}], and the result is being written to file: {filePath}");
    
                    using (var audioDataStream = AudioDataStream.FromResult(result))
                    {
                        await audioDataStream.SaveToWaveFileAsync(filePath);
                    }
                }
                else if (result.Reason == ResultReason.Canceled)
                {
                    var cancellation = SpeechSynthesisCancellationDetails.FromResult(result);
                    Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: Reason={cancellation.Reason}");
                    if (cancellation.Reason == CancellationReason.Error)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: ErrorCode={cancellation.ErrorCode}");
                        Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: ErrorDetails= [{cancellation.ErrorDetails}]");
                        Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: Did you set the speech resource key and region values?");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I tried the following sample Blazor server app code to convert text to speech without playing it in the browser.*

**Code :**

***TextToSpeechServivce.cs :***

```cs
using Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech;
using Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.Audio;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BlazorApp12.Services
{
    public class TextToSpeechService
    {
        public async Task<string> ConvertTextToSpeech(string textToSpeak)
        {
            string subscriptionKey = "<speech_key>";
            string region = "<speech_region>";
            string outputFilePath = "wwwroot\\Audio\\DictationRecordings\\output.wav";

            var config = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription(subscriptionKey, region);
            using var synthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer(config, AudioConfig.FromWavFileOutput(outputFilePath));

            await synthesizer.SpeakTextAsync(textToSpeak);

            return outputFilePath;
        }
    }
}
```

***index.raror :***

```html
@page "/"
@using BlazorApp12.Services
@inject TextToSpeechService TextToSpeechService

<h3>Text-to-Speech Conversion</h3>

<div>
    <label for="textInput">Enter Text:</label>
    <input type="text" id="textInput" @bind="TextToSpeak" />
    <button @onclick="ConvertTextToSpeech">Convert</button>
</div>

@if (IsConversionDone)
{
    <p>Text-to-speech conversion completed. Output file saved at: @OutputFilePath</p>
}

@code {
    private string TextToSpeak { get; set; } = "Hello, this is a test.";
    private bool IsConversionDone { get; set; } = false;
    private string OutputFilePath { get; set; }

    private async Task ConvertTextToSpeech()
    {
        OutputFilePath = await TextToSpeechService.ConvertTextToSpeech(TextToSpeak);
        IsConversionDone = true;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

The code ran successfully, as shown below:

[image]

***Browser output:***

I received the following page in my browser: I wrote a line and clicked the "**Convert**" button. This action converted the text to speech and saved the speech audio to an **output.wav file without playing it in the browser**, as shown below.

[image]

The audio is saved to the **output.wav** file below.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. It is finally working, really awesome. Meanwhile i used ElevenLabs Text-To-Speech, which sounds really better. But also MS TTS is good.